# is it possible to run rake tasks from another server in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, cron, rake-task

I have a bookmarking website developed in ruby on rails 3.0.7 and many rake file are running every time to get bookmarked URLs details and added users informations. Since rake are running every time, my server got engaged and its CPU utilization is 100%. I need to run my rake files in another server by saving all rakes in database and put it in a queue.

I set one cron in separate server to process the rake tasks's queue with my files shared. But the rake tasks are still running from the development server.

Is there any option to run rake files in another server? or How can I set dynamic cron jobs in rails?

Please help me

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for a background worker. There are many solutions for ruby.

The basic idea is this: you submit tasks to a queue (backed by [redis](/questions/tagged/redis)/[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)/whatever). Then another process (worker) pops tasks from the queue and executes them in background, without blocking or affecting your app. Naturally, you can have multiple workers and they can be located on other machines.

Here's a collection of railscasts about workers: [Background Job railscasts](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=32).

My current favourite is Sidekiq.